# avoiding simultaneous execution of shell command with node.js & shelljs

Tags: javascript, node.js

Using nodejs 8.12 on Gnu/Linux CentOS 7. Using the built-in web server, require('https'), for a simple application.

I understand that nodejs is single threaded (single process) and there is no actual parallel execution of code. Based on my understanding, I think the http/https server will process one http request and run the handler through all synchronous statements and set up asynchronous statements to be executed later before it will return to process a subsequent request. However, with http/https libraries, you have an asynchronous code that is used to assemble the body of the request. So, we already have one callback which is executed when the body is ready ('end' event). This fact makes me think it might be possible to be in the middle of processing two or more requests simultaneously.

As part of handling the requests, I need to execute a string of shell commands and I use the shelljs.exec library to do that. It runs synchronously, waiting until complete before returning. So, example code would look like:

```
const shelljs_exec = require('shelljs.exec');
function process() {
   // bunch of shell commands in string
   var command_str = 'command1; command2; command3';
   var exec_results = shelljs_exec(command_str);
   console.log('just executed shelljs_exec command');
   var proc_results = process_results(exec_results);
   console.log(proc_results);
   // and return the response... 
}
```

So node.js runs the shelljs_exec() and waits for completion. While it's waiting, can another request be worked on, such that there is a risk, slight, of two or more shelljs.exec invocations running at the same time? Since that could be a problem, I need to ensure only one shelljs.exec statement can be in progress at a given time.

If that is not a correct understanding, then I was thinking I need to do something with mutex locks. Like this:

```
const shelljs_exec = require('shelljs.exec');
const locks = require('locks');

// Need this in global scope - so we are all dealing with the same one.
var mutex = locks.createMutex();

function await_lock(shell_commands) {
  var commands = shell_commands;
  return new Promise(getting_lock => {
    mutex.lock(got_lock_and_execute);
  });

  function got_lock_and_execute() {
    var exec_results = shelljs_exec(commands);
    console.log('just executed shelljs_exec command');
    mutex.unlock();
    return exec_results;
  }
}

async function process() {
  // bunch of shell commands in string
  var command_str = 'command1; command2; command3';
  exec_results = await await_lock(command_str);
  var proc_results = process_results(exec_results);
  console.log(proc_results);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `shelljs_exec` is synchronous, no need.

If it is not. If it takes a callback wrap it in a Promise constructor so that it can be awaited. I would suggest properly wrapping the `mutex.lock` in a promise that gets resolved when the lock is acquired. The try finally is needed to ensure that the `mutex` is unlocked if `shelljs_exec` throws an exception.

```
async function await_lock(shell_commands) {
  await (new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    mutex.lock(resolve);
  }));
  try {
    let exec_results = await shelljs_exec(commands);
    return exec_results;
  } finally {
    mutex.unlock();
  }
}
```

Untested. But it looks like it should work.

Comment: Your first sentence is the answer. However, I dug into the async/await code you provided, but it didn't work. The promise is never resolved. I worked on it further, but didn't get it fully working. Here is the code:

Comment: const shelljs_exec = require('shelljs.exec');
const locks = require('locks');
var mutex = locks.createMutex();

function got_lock() {
    console.log('got_lock: got the lock');
    mutex.unlock();
}

function promise_cb(resolve, reject) {
   console.log('promise_cb: resolve = ' + resolve);
   mutex.lock(got_lock);
   console.log('promise_cb: after mutex.lock');
}

Comment: // and...
async function await_lock(cmds) {
   await (new Promise(promise_cb));
   console.log('done with await');
   try {
       let results = await shelljs_exec(cmds);
       return results;
   } catch {
       mutex.unlock();
   }
}